# Update span value based on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a span where I would like to update its value to be equal to an input field. I know it's possible for an input, but is it also possible for a span?

HTML:

```
<p style='font-size:150%'>
Hey bro, I am <span id='name_display'>Anonymous</span>，

I'd like to invite you to.....

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id='name' placeholder="your name">

</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").click(function() {
            $("#name_display").val( $("#name").val() );
    });    
});
```

Not working so far. Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close, but two things:

1. `span` elements don't have values, they have *content*. You can set that content with [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html):

   ```
   $("#name_display").text( $("#name").val() );
   // Or
   $("#name_display").html( $("#name").val() );
   ```

   `text` will make sure to HTML-encode the text (so a `<` comes out as a `<`), `html` interprets the text you give it as HTML.
2. You're updating when the user *clicks* the text field, which is an odd time to update. You might update on `change` (but it won't update until after the user leaves the field), `keypress`, `input`, or indeed a combination:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#name").on("change keypress input", function() {
           $("#name_display").text( $("#name").val() );
       });    
   });
   ```

Separately, within the event callback, the element on which you hooked the event is given to you as `this`, so we can make a slight change there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").on("change keypress input", function() {
        $("#name_display").text( $(this).val() ); // <= Change on this line
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the span's content with .html, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").click(function() {
            $("#name_display").html( $("#name").val() );
    });    
});
```

Comment: Apologies. Updated my comment.